# Is it possible to construct a positive random variable such that truncated means are always linear?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable that takes positive values. Let $\tau \in (0,\infty)$ be a truncation point. Is it possible to construct a distribution of $X$ such that both $u(\tau):=\mathbb{E}[X\mid X\ge \tau]$ and $l(\tau):=\mathbb{E}[X\mid X\le \tau]$ are linear in $\tau$?

Intuitively, if the density of $X$ has a peak, then the rate of change in $u$ and $l$ cannot be constant, so I guess it should have a monotone density?

For example, if $X$ follows the exponential distribution with scale $\beta$, then $u(\tau)=\beta + \tau$ and $l(\tau)=\beta - \tau/(\exp(\beta^{-1}\tau - 1)$. Thus, $u$ is linear but $l$ is not linear in $\tau$. I tried to work from here by considering a weighted density or mixture of densities of exponential form, but I haven't gotten any results.

Comment: Seeing the answers posted, I realized that it must be $\lim_{\tau\to\infty} l(\tau)=\mathbb{E}[X]$, so if $X$ has a finite first moment, then $l$ cannot be linear.

Comment: Even if $X$ does not have a finite first moment, then $l$ cannot be linear.

Comment: Yes I meant as a simple proof in a restricted case

Comment: However, it is possible to get "as close as you want" to being linear. For example, take the [Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) with a small $\alpha>0$, then $$ l(\tau) = \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}(\tau^{1-\alpha} - 1).$$

Comment: If $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[a,b]$ then the conditional expectations will be linear when $a < \tau <b$.  You can let $a=0$ but you cannot let $b=\infty$ and still have a distribution

Comment: @Henry Yes, and for my purpose, I wanted to know if it is possible for unbounded support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no positive distribution such that the random variable satisfies $$\mathbb{E}[X\mid X\le \tau] = a\tau + b,$$ for constants $a,b\in\mathbb R$.

---

First, let us handle the case of a proper continuous positive distribution. Suppose there exists such distribution with pdf $f$ and cdf $F$.

We have $b = 0$ because $\mathbb E[X\mid X\le 0] = 0$.
From the definition of conditioned expectation, we have that
\begin{align}
  \int_0^\tau x f(x) dx = a\tau F(\tau).
\end{align}
Taking the derivative with respect to $\tau$ we have
\begin{align}
  \tau f(\tau) = a\tau f(\tau) + aF(\tau).
\end{align}
Rearranging we get the following equation and conclude that $a\in(0,1)$,
$$
  f(\tau) = \frac{a}{1-a}\frac{F(\tau)}{\tau}.
$$
Now we integrate with respect to $\tau$ from $0$ to $\infty$. The left-hand side results in $1$, and the right-hand side diverges because $F(\tau) \to 1$ as $\tau\to \infty$.

---

The case of an improper distribution is analogous and the case of a non-continuous distribution cannot work because $\frac{d}{d\tau} \mathbb{E}[X \,\mathbf{1}_{X\le \tau}]$ must be well defined and equal to a constant.

Comment: Could you elaborate why the integral of $F(\tau)/\tau$ diverges? I can see that $\int_0^\infty F(\tau)$ diverges, but since $F(\tau)/\tau \to 0$, I'm not sure why it diverges.

Comment: because $\int_{c_1}^\infty \frac{c_2}{x} dx$ diverges for any $c_1 > 0$ and $c_2>0$.

Comment: and there exists $c_1>0$ and $c_2>0$ such that $F(\tau) > c_2$ for every $\tau > c_1$.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $X$ is a nonnegative random variable. If $\mathbb E[X|\{X \le t\}] = at + b$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb R$ and every $t \ge 0$, as in P.S. Dester answer we conclude that $b=0$. Hence, for $t$ large enough, $$ at = \mathbb E[X|\{X \le t\}] = \frac{1}{\mathbb P(X \le t)} \mathbb E[X1_{\{X \le t\}}].$$ Rearranging, $$ a \mathbb P(X \le t) = \mathbb E[ \frac{X}{t} 1_{\{X \le t\}}].$$ The left hand side converges to $a$ as $t \to +\infty$, whereas by the Dominated Convergence Theorem the right hand side converges to $0$. Therefore, $a=0$, but then $\mathbb E[X|\{X \le t\}] = 0$ for every $t \ge 0$, which yields $X = 0$ a.e (since then $\mathbb E[X 1_{\{X \le t\}}] = 0$ for every $t \ge 0$).

Answer (score 0):

When I first read the question I assumed "linear" meant "asymptotically linear" (i.e. $\Theta(\tau)$) rather than "exactly equal to an affine function of $\tau$". But even this much weaker condition is impossible.

Suppose there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\mathbb{E}(X\mid X\leq \tau)\geq \varepsilon \tau$ for every $\tau$ sufficiently large. Now for any distribution there is some $\kappa$ such that $\Pr(X\leq \kappa\mid X<\infty)> 1-\varepsilon/2$. Simply take $\tau=2\varepsilon^{-1}\kappa$.

Now $\Pr(X\leq \kappa\mid X\leq\tau)\geq\Pr(X\leq \kappa\mid X<\infty)> 1-\varepsilon/2$. We have $\mathbb{E}(X\mid X\leq\kappa)\leq\kappa$, and $\mathbb{E}(X\mid \kappa< X\leq\tau)\leq\tau$. Thus
$$\mathbb{E}(X\mid X\leq \tau)=\Pr(X\leq \kappa\mid X\leq \tau)\mathbb{E}(X\mid X\leq\kappa)+\Pr(X>\kappa\mid X\leq \tau)(\mathbb{E}(X\mid \kappa<X\leq \tau)\\
<\kappa+\varepsilon\tau/2=\varepsilon\tau,$$
a contradiction.